# Am I able to serialize the Transaction Builder to send it to another party?

Tags: corda

Is there anyway to serialize a transaction builder?

I’m trying to use the TwoPartyDealFlow to enable two parties to trade on-ledger tokens. I need to be able to add input states / outputs states / commands on both sides in order to use the `.generateMove` functionality from the token sdk.

Let me know if this is possible or if I should be using a different method.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and perhaps better) way would be to request the input/output states you require from counterparties and then add them to the TransactionBuilder.

You could do this from within a flow session using SendAndReceive.

Comment: Thanks, Cais - that's what I ended up doing. Along with the generated commands.